# NHibernate - is there a tool to generate POCOs?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, poco

I'm looking into using NHibernate and all looks good. Is there a tool that I can use to generate POCOs from the current database? This will speed up developer time rapidly as opposed to creating them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NHibernate mapping generator project ( http://nmg.codeplex.com/ ) can create both the entity classes and all forms of mappings (XML, fluent nhibernate etc).

Answer (score 0):

The Entity Framework Power Tools can generate POCOs for you, from a database. See [this article](http://romiller.com/2012/05/09/customizing-reverse-engineer-code-first-in-the-ef-power-tools/) for some information. You might need to tweak the process a bit though; a bit of tweaking can produce very good results:

> If everything lines up then we don’t generate any mapping at all:
>
> [image: EFPT]

Of course, if everything doesn't line up then you get Entity Framework-specific attributes applied that you'll need to remove. But you'll still have a good starting point.

<sub>Personal Opinion Alert! Another possibility would be simply to keep the attributes and use the Entity Framework. I would recommend it if you make heavy use of LINQ. I find NHibernate's LINQ provider works for the most part but bombs out with 1) extremely trivial LINQ expressions and 2) extremely complex LINQ expressions. *But ta.speot.is! It's getting better all the time!* Each to their own, but right now the Entity Framework's LINQ provider is extremely consistent.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick SQL script to create both the poco and map.  Feel free to adjust as needed.

```
    begin

    declare @tablename varchar(200)
    set @tablename = 'tablename'

    declare @outputTable table ( id int identity(1,1), rowType varchar(4), outputString varchar(5000))
    declare @columnname varchar(200)
    declare @isNullable bit
    declare @xtype tinyint
    declare @xtypeString varchar(200)
    declare @outputString varchar(5000)

    declare c1 cursor for 
        select name, isnullable, xtype from syscolumns
            where id in (select id  from sysobjects where name = @tablename)
            order by colorder

    open c1

    set @outputString = 'Table("' +  Upper(@tablename) + '");'

    insert into @outputTable (rowType, outputString) values('map',@outputString)

    fetch next from c1 into @columnName, @isNullable, @xtype
    while(@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
    begin

    print @columnname
    print @isnullable
    print @xtype

    set @outputString = ''
    set @xtypeString = ''

    if (@xtype = 104)
        set @xtypeString = 'bool'

    if (@xtype = 60)
        set @xtypeString = 'double'

    if (@xtype = 62)
        set @xtypeString = 'double'

    if (@xtype = 175)
        set @xtypeString = 'string'

    if (@xtype = 56)
        set @xtypeString = 'int'

    if (@xtype = 48)
        set @xtypeString = 'int'

    if (@xtype = 167)
        set @xtypeString = 'string'

    if (@xtype = 61)
        set @xtypeString = 'DateTime'

    if (@isnullable = 1 and len(@xtypeString) > 0 and @xtypeString <> 'string') 
        set @xtypeString = @xtypeString + '?'

    if @xtypeString=''
        set @xtypeString = cast(@xtype as varchar)

    set @outputString = 'public virtual ' + @xtypeString + '   ' +  @columnName + '  {get;set;}          //  ' + @columnname

    insert into @outputTable (rowType, outputString)    values('poco', @outputString)

    set @outputString = 'Map(x => x.'+ @columnname+').Column("' + @columnname+'");'

    insert into @outputTable (rowType, outputString)    values('map', @outputString)


    fetch next from c1 into @columnName, @isNullable, @xtype
    end

    close c1
    deallocate c1

    select * from @outputTable where rowType = 'poco' order by id 
    select * from @outputTable where rowType = 'map' order by id 
end
```